# get unique without sorting in jq

Tags: jq

Array => `["cross", "base", "cross", "dunk"]`

I want to delete all repeated values without sorting.

Command: `jq '. | unique' file.json`

Output: `["base", "cross", "dunk"]`

Expected Output: `["cross", "base", "dunk"]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
map({key:.,value:1})|from_entries|keys_unsorted
```

as an alternative to `unique` seems to work.

`map` turns the array into:

```
[{"key":"cross","value":1},{"key":"base","value":1},{"key":"cross","value":1},{"key":"dunk","value":1}]
```

`from_entries` turns that into:

```
{"cross":1,"base":1,"dunk":1}
```

Removing the duplicates at that point since two elements of an object can't have the same key.

And `keys_unsorted` returns the keys of that object, in the original order.

A shorter/simpler alternative working on the same principle:

```
map({(.):1})|add|keys_unsorted
```

---

Or you can use a more generic programming language such as `perl`:

```
perl -l -0777 -MJSON::PP -MList::Util=uniq -pe '
  $_ = encode_json[uniq @{decode_json $_}]' array.json
```

`-p` is the sed mode, pull each record of `array.json` into `$_` for the `e`expression to work on.

`-0777` sets the record separator to something impossible, meaning there's only one record being the full file (see also `-g`obble in newer versions of `perl`).

`decode_json $_` decodes that record and returns an array reference, `@{...}` makes that a list passed to `uniq`, `[...]` makes the result another array reference passed to `encode_json`, the resulting `$_` is printed (followed by a newline with `-l`).

There are  a number of JSON plugins for perl. JSON::PP (PP for pure perl) is part of the core of perl, so should always be available. JSON::XS would be more efficient and also comes with a `json_xs` which is handy to use in shell scripts:

```
json_xs -e 'use List::Util "uniq"; $_ = [uniq @$_]' < array.json
```

If you're already familiar with `perl`, that means you don't need to learn a new language like that of `jq`s and can reuse what you know to process other formats like XML, YAML, etc.

Comment: I'd love to know some good reference for jq (with many exemples, ained at people that already handle scripting langages so quite short and to the point, or maybe cookbook style?) if you (or anyone reading this) have some. I had one that "opened" awk to me initially, but haven't found it for jq yet

Comment: @OlivierDulac, I use `man jq` for reference. For examples, you can look at answers here. Look out for Kusalanda's for instance.

Comment: @OlivierDulac The online manual is the same as the manual you get with `man`, but is conveniently searchable and possibly more readable than the ordinary text manual.  It is also easy to point to separate sections in it. See e.g. the `reduce()` function: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Reduce

Comment: This solution picks the "last value in input array", while the @Kusalananda answer picks the "first value in input array"

Answer (score 4):

Using `reduce()` to build the resulting array of unique elements from the input:

```bash
jq 'reduce .[] as $a ([]; if IN(.[]; $a) then . else . += [$a] end)' file.json
```

This essentially iterates over the array in `file.json`, adding each element to a new array unless it's already present in that array.

Testing:

```bash
$ jq . file.json
[
  "cross",
  "base",
  "cross",
  "dunk"
]
```

```bash
$ jq 'reduce .[] as $a ([]; if IN(.[]; $a) then . else . += [$a] end)' file.json
[
  "cross",
  "base",
  "dunk"
]
```

Comment: Great. It picks the "first element found" instead of the "last element" like the accepted answer does